# How to create XLL file using c++ with range?

Tags: c++

I want to create user functions Excel using c++.
I created simple user functions but I don't know how to create it with parameter is range.

Thanks for reading and help me.

Comment: what have you tried so far? where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3):

For User Defined Functions (UDF) to accept XL ranges as arguments or return variables you need to use XLOPER in c++. This is part of the Microsoft Excel SDK.
I suggest you compile some of the sample code from the SDK and start to learn about it from there.

Here is an example from the SDK, where LPXLOPER12 is used in XL 2007+

```
/*
** fArray
**
** This example consists of two routines: fArray and xlAutoFree().
** This function creates an xltypeMulti containing eight values. It returns
** this array to Microsoft Excel with the xlbitDLLFree bit set. When
** Microsoft Excel is done with the values, it calls xlAutoFree(), which
** frees the memory that fArray() allocated.
*/

HANDLE hArray;

__declspec(dllexport) LPXLOPER12 WINAPI fArray(void)
{
    LPXLOPER12 pxArray;
    static XLOPER12 xMulti;
    int i;
    int rwcol;

    xMulti.xltype = xltypeMulti | xlbitDLLFree;
    xMulti.val.array.columns = 1;
    xMulti.val.array.rows = 8;

    //For large values of rows and columns, this would overflow
    //use __int64 in that case and return an error if rwcol
    //contains a number that won't fit in sizeof(int) bytes

    rwcol = xMulti.val.array.columns * xMulti.val.array.rows; 

    pxArray = (LPXLOPER12)GlobalLock(hArray = GlobalAlloc(GMEM_ZEROINIT, rwcol * sizeof(XLOPER12)));

    xMulti.val.array.lparray = pxArray;

    for(i = 0; i < rwcol; i++) 
    {
        pxArray[i].xltype = xltypeInt;
        pxArray[i].val.w = i;
    }

    //Word of caution - returning static XLOPERs/XLOPER12s is not thread safe
    //for UDFs declared as thread safe, use alternate memory allocation mechanisms

    return (LPXLOPER12)&xMulti;
}

__declspec(dllexport) void WINAPI xlAutoFree12(LPXLOPER12 pxFree)
{
    GlobalUnlock(hArray);
    GlobalFree(hArray);
    return;
}
```

Comment: You can send example to me, pls?